# How long is the transition period from a developer-for-hire position to full time position?

Tags: job-change, contracts, fulltime

From my current organization (A), I am working as a developer-for-hire for another organization (B) for last one year.

(B) has been quite happy with my work and wants to hire me for a full-time position and they have approached (A) saying so.

I was told by (A) about the same and they told me that it would take 1 year for transition & I would have to work for 1 year from (A) before switching to (B).

I am not sure but 1 year feels too long. Is there any industry standard for this?

I am aware that it would ultimately be decided by the contract between (A) & (B) but I just wanted to know anyways that do I have any say in how long the transition period should be?

Comment: We are not party to any contract between And B, and we are not party to any contract between you and A. What makes you think that we can give you any knowledgeable advice as to whether you have a say without us knowing the contents of the contracts? However, this is not say that the contract govern every transaction. I got involved once on behalf of a former junior who had gone into consulting. The client was so happy with his work that they called me for a reference check pending an offer to him. Ordinarily, the consulting company wouldn't let go of him but they did. To keep the client happy.

Comment: Why can't you just contract with B alone and resign from A?

Comment: Questions seeking advice on company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies should be directed to your manager or HR department. Questions that address only a specific company or position are of limited use to future visitors. Questions seeking legal advice should be directed to legal professionals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the situation you describe...a lot can depend on what kind of contract you signed when you began your employment with Company A. When working for an agency on-site at a vendor, for example, I've seen agency contracts that stipulate 90 days, and others that stipulate one year. It varies completely, even in the same city and industry. There is no "standard" - though years ago, there seemed to be a de-facto standard of 90 days. Now, it varies wildly.

There may be clauses in whatever contract you signed, saying that (for example) you cannot go to work for Company B -=in the exact same position on the exact same team=- as you were, when employed with Company A.

I do not personally know of any situations where the developer had any say over the maximum length of the transition period. Doesn't mean that it hasn't happened...just that I don't know of any such situations. I would think that it might be something that could be negotiated during the initial phase - before the developer accepts any role with Company A, at any company. But again, I'm not sure. (There may even be different rights that people would have in different jurisdictions. But also, Companies A and B probably have longer-standing business relationships, and Company A really really would not want to damage that - seeing as that is some or potentially a large portion of Company B's income, is developers that they have working on-site at Company A.)

Read over the contract you signed, see exactly what it says. Then ask the labor ombudsman for your local area about legal resources you could ask. But also bring your on-site manager at Company B into the loop at least a little, just so that they're aware of what you're looking into and why.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "industry standard" as "standards" are based off where you are, your specific industry, and your specific situation. In this case, it sounds like it is "standard" for Company (A) to require 1 full year's work before transitioning you to Company (B), though we won't actually know that without seeing the various contracts surrounding your hire (including the contracts between Company (A) and (B).

An example is that I work for company (X) but I am hired through Staffing Agency (Y). There is typically a 90-day minimum with this staffing agency before I am allowed to switch to Staffing Agency (Z). However due to demand, both (X) and (Y) came to an agreement to allow my switch before the 90-day mark.

It sounds to me like your situation may be a little different. If you are working temp-to-hire, it is likely that you are hired through some form of consulting agency. These companies only make money as long as you are staffed through them, being hired on full-time to Company (B) will likely stop them from making money off of you.

An example in this case was a contract-to-hire software developer position that I worked for. The contract between *my* employer and the company I worked for billed them at $60/hr, while I was given $35/hr. I would had to work 6 months minimum before I could directly work for the other company (though I did quit after just 2 months).

Likely you won't have any say in this matter, but why not confirm that with your manager instead?